# Hyphen Suffix on file name

Tags: linux, etc, passwd, shadow

I decided to randomly take a look at my /etc directory, and I saw some entries like this:

```
passwd
passwd-
shadow
shadow-
subgid
subgid-
```

I know they are hyphens (`-`) and not tildes (`~`). What are the files with a hyphen suffix for (as opposed to their non-hyphened counterparts)?

Comment: Those are backups.

Comment: Ok, that is an odd way to do it then... Usually people use ~ or .bak. Nice to know that though.

Comment: Agreed, but Google didn't give me that page, so I will let this point to that so people can find it.